# Different outcome of Excel intracell formatting macro on different workbooks

Tags: excel, formatting, vba

I have written a simple Excel VBA macro to have different formatting in a single cell.  I have a formula that returns one of 4 possible values:

1. l1
2. l2
3. l3
4. l4

I wish to format this as Wingdings for the first character with a colour based on the number - 1 = red, 2 = orange, 3 = yellow and 4 = green.
[image: Excel formatting image]

What I have done is to put in an event trigger on cell change:

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call Wingdings(Target)
End Sub`

The subroutine is as follows:

```
Sub Wingdings(rCll As Range)

If rCll.Value = "l1" Or rCll.Value = "l2" Or _
    rCll.Value = "l3" Or rCll.Value = "l4" Then
    Select Case Right(rCll.Value, 1)

    Case 1 'Red
        With rCll.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    Case 2 'Orange
        With rCll.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        End With

    Case 3 'Yellow
        With rCll.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        End With
    Case 4 'Green
        With rCll.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
            .Name = "Wingdings"
            .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End With
    End Select
End If
```

End Sub

My issue here is that if I manually enter eg l4, the code runs perfectly.  But as soon as I determine this value using a formula, it stops working as I desire.  I end up with this:
[image: What I get with a formula]

Can anyone suggest a solution to allow me to format the result of the formula as I desire?

Comment: It probably has to do with the formatting of your Formula Cells. Try some comparissons by hand. For example =Right(Formulacell1;1)=1 to check if the matches are really there, or that for example your formula cell makes use of a different formatting and therefore no match is found.

Comment: You could force the formulas into values before the first check line, something like   `rCll.value = rCll.value` or do use one of the many ways to `cells.copy` - `.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: It looks like this is not because of a formula, but if you drag the formula to autofill. Te macro only seems to trigger the one time.If you add this to a loop  on each cell in the range you will likely get what you want

Answer (score 0):

What you have works.

Maybe call something like this on the Change event instead, conditionally, if you are dragging formulas

```
Sub fixstuff()
    For Each cell In Selection
     cell.Select
     Call Wingdings(Range(cell.Address))
    Next cell
   End Sub
```